# Domain transfer to AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have tried to move my wordpress website to AWS hosting.  Domain is registered with 123-reg and I have updated the NS there (and checked to confirm the change has occured).

In AWS I have followed the tutorials to set up a new EC2 server, install LAMP and wordpress and all the tests came back fine.  Have also configured loadbalancer.

I have two domains (enablie.com and enablie.co.uk) so have tried one version with an elastic IP and one without to see if it makes a difference, but it doesn't seem to.

Now that I have tried to route the domains the sites do not appear to be working - when I try to log in to upload my wordpress site via Updraft it naviagated away from the site to this address http://ec2-35-177-92-36.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-login.php and then says cannot open page as server not responding.  When I manually change this back to enablie.co.uk/wp-login.php I can add by login details, but it again naviates back to http://ec2-35-177-92-36.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-login.php with the same error message.

I have tried to fix this by updating the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in the wp-config.php file, but it hasn't fixes it.

I have gone through the various related questions on here, but can't find anything that fixes the issue.  Please advise what else I should try.

Thanks

Lisa

Comment: Did you create the virtualhost for those domains?

Comment: Yes I did - all set up new

Comment: it seems your URLs in your theme are wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Issue now resolved - database entries still pointed to old url.  Updated via mysql and now all working well.

Used the below after selecting the right database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```